# How do you do multiple joins three joined tables to a fourth table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The database schema for this question is located here: [db fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43f791)

I am trying to do the following:

1. Join table A (group table) to table J (grouprooms)
2. Join table B (room table) to table J (grouprooms)
3. Finally Join table C (users) table A - note table A already joined to J

I have written a query that accomplishes steps 1 and 2 but can't figure out how to join the users table to the group table.

Here's the query I have so far:

```
select rooms.room_name, groups.group_name, groups.group_ID 
from grouprooms 
left join rooms on grouprooms.room_ID = rooms.room_ID 
left join groups on grouprooms.group_ID = groups.group_ID;
```

Comment: What is the relation between `users` and other tables ? It would be good if you could update your question to add sample data and expected results.

Comment: @GMB user has a group_ID foreign key

Comment: OK so maybe you just want to add one more join to your query, like `left join users on users.group_id = groups.group_id` ?

Comment: ultimately I want a query that shows all users names, groups they are in and the rooms they have access too.

Comment: OK then. Please edit your question to show sample data and expected output and you will sure get an accurate answer.

Comment: @GMB when I add the new join the query returns results, however, when I also add users.name to the select line it does not return anything.  typo - that works.  Do you want to give a response that I can select.

Comment: [This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43f791/5) looks good to me. Last lines have no user names because : there is no user in group 3, and last group room is not linked to a group

Answer (score 0):

You could just add another `LEFT JOIN` to your query to link in table `users` :

```
select rooms.room_name, groups.group_name, users.name 
from grouprooms 
left join rooms on grouprooms.room_ID = rooms.room_ID 
left join groups on grouprooms.group_ID = groups.group_ID
left join users on grouprooms.group_id = users.group_id
```

See [your updated db fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43f791/5) :

- grouproom 6 is showing no user because there is no user in group 3 (OPERATIONS)
- grouproom 7 is not linked to a group, hence it has no group name and no user